# [ViewPager][Toolbar] Getting menu action items only for single fragment of all the fragments in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a view fragment as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                android:layout_height="300dp"
                                                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout android:id="@+id/word_view_appbar_collapsing"
                                                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                               android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                               app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                                                               app:expandedTitleGravity="center|bottom"
                                                               app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/AppBarTitleExpanded">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/word_view_toolbar"
                                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                               android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                                               app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                                               app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                android:fillViewport="true"
                                                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This fragment is used to load similar swipable views using `FragmentStatePageAdapter`.

I only get the action menu items displayed in one of the fragments(not on a selected fragment), if in a fragment `onCreateView` method I take a reference to a toolbar and set it as an ActionBar as follows:

```
final Toolbar wordViewToolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.word_view_toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(wordViewToolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

But I get the menu action items in all the fragments if I do not set the toolbar as an action bar and do as follows:

```
final Toolbar wordViewToolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.word_view_toolbar);
wordViewToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.word_view_app_bar_menu);
```

I would prefer taking the first approach since every interaction will be taken care of by Android. Still I want to know how to get the Ist approach working like IInd, and what is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you must call `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()`, I would advise against doing so from within a Fragment. Call it from the Activity.

If your fragments contains a menu then just this to each Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true); // This Fragment has a menu
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment, menu); // Inflate the Fragment's menu
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    int id = item.getItemId();

    // Handle Fragment menu clicks
    switch(id){
        case R.id.action_do_something:
            // do something
            return true;

        case R.id.action_do_something_else:
            // do something else
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Please refer my fragment xml, as I have declared Toolbar, until I add it as a supportActionBar your code will not work.

Comment: @Aki008 I don't know what sort of menu behavior you're trying to achieve then. Fragments are meant to handle content and Activities typically handle the base layout and menu.